# Run scripts which are stored in GitLab from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, git, gitlab, github, shell-script

I have configured Jenkins Build Jobs and Deployment Jobs from using Jenkins shell. But I put all the commands in Shell to execute. Can I store those commands in GitLab and execute from jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Gitlab merely as a source code repository, and you are triggering the jobs when there are changes to the repository.

The [Jenkins Gitlab plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin) documentations states:

> This plugin is a build trigger that allows GitLab to trigger Jenkins builds when code is pushed or a merge request is created. Configuration done on a per-job basis.

So, you can trigger the builds. But to answer your question:

> I put all the commands in Shell to execute. Can I store those commands in GitLab and execute from jenkins?

The answer is **yes**, but there is some leeway. It depends on how you've configured the jobs. If they are freestyle jobs, have them execute a shell command running the script in your repository. You can do this via the web-interface the Jenkins job editor.

However, I wouldn't recommend this as best practice. Instead, I would recommend having a pipeline description in the repository. See [the plugin docs on github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#jenkins-job-configuration) for more details on configuration.